# How I get the internal html content of a div tag using Apache Wicket

Tags: javascript, html, wicket, wicket-1.6, wicket-6

In my html file I have a div tag like this,

```
<div wicket:id="editorArea">Type Here</div>
```

I am using a JavaScript library called [bootstrap-wysiwyg](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) to make this div tag a text are which we can type rich text. When the person types text, div tag's html content updates to represent the text content in html. I want to retrieve it in to the Java code of the html file in wicket. I tried to do it by creating reference variable to div tag like following,

```
WebMarkupContainer editorArea=new WebMarkupContainer("editorArea");
String text=editorArea.getMarkup().toString(true)
```

But this don't give me the updated HTML content. I give only the initial html content. what is the problem here?

Comment: Take a look on how the AjaxEditableLabel from the wicket-extensions works. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: I tried to use it like this,   AjaxEditableMultiLineLabel ajaxEditableMultiLineLabel=new AjaxEditableMultiLineLabel("editorArea");
  ajaxEditableMultiLineLabel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
  ajaxEditableMultiLineLabel.setMarkupId("editorArea");
  form.add(ajaxEditableMultiLineLabel); But it give following exception java.lang.IllegalStateException: No model found for this component, either pass one explicitly or make sure an inheritable model is available.
     at org.apache.wicket.extensions.ajax.markup.html.AjaxEditableLabel.getParentModel(AjaxEditableLabel.java:577)

Comment: You need to provide a Model (to the constructor or as a CompoundModel to it's parent tree). That's where wicket put's the HTML content.

Comment: I got it working by String value="Type....."; ajaxEditableLabel=new AjaxEditableLabel("editorArea",new Model(value));. Now my javascript is working. But how can I get the updated value of label? Do I have to override onEdit method ?

Comment: The updated value *should* be stored in your 'value' variable.

Comment: I have created a submit button in my from. There I check the value variable value. But it not updated :(

Comment: I added this and some additional info as an answer...

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add editorArea to the html code first

```
WebMarkupContainer editorArea=new WebMarkupContainer("editorArea");
add(editorArea);
String text=editorArea.getMarkup().toString(true)
```

Comment: This want work. The method editorArea.getMarkup().toString(true) return only the initial markup. The dynamically(JS) updated markup is not coming.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at AjaxEditableLabel from the wicket-extensions.

The Label will update it's model with the typed content

There is an example at the [Wicket Library](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/editable-label), showing how it can be used. This example uses an CompoundPropertyModel but can easily adapable to work with other types of models too.

Comment: I have corrected my problem via another method. But your answer helped me a lot. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

getMarkup() only gives you the markupfile for the component if I read the javadoc right. Try either

```
editorArea.getModelObject()
```

or

```
editorArea.getValue()
```

The first one is preferred but because the editorArea is a WebMarkupContainer it might not work as intended.